# How to render conditionally based on alternating patterns?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have a list of products that I want to display in a card view. The card background should go like this: Green, Blue, Red, Purple, Green, Blue, Red, Purple, etc etc

```
products.map(item => (
    <div style="background-color: {bgColor}"> 
       <h1>{item.name}<h1>
    </div>
    { bgColor === 'green'&& setBgColor('blue')}
    { bgColor === 'blue' && setBgColor('red')}
    { bgColor === 'red' && setBgColor('purple')}
    { bgColor === 'purple' && setBgColor('blue')}
))}
```

This code obviously doesn't work because it'll end up in a never ending loop.

But essentially I'd like the map function to consider what state the color is in, and for the NEXT render in the products array, change the color to a different color.

Logically, I'm trying to say the below code for each map item

```
if (bgColor === 'green') { 
   setBgcolor: 'blue'
   return
}
if (bgColor === 'blue') { 
   setBgcolor: 'red'
   return
}
if (bgColor === 'red') { 
   setBgcolor: 'purple'
   return
}
if (bgColor === 'purple') { 
   setBgcolor: 'green'
   return
}
```

I'm open to completely different methods of implementing this however..

Comment: Refactor your function: create a local variable that contains a copy of bgColor. Then have the logic that changes bgColor. Then return the div that uses the previously stored local variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood your issue correctly, you can create a map of colors based on the remainder when you divide the item `index` by 4.

This code should render 'blue' when the item's index is 0/4/8... etc.

```
const colorMap = {
 0: 'blue',
 1: 'red',
 2: 'green',
 3: 'purple'
}

products.map((item, index) => (
    <div style="background-color: {colorMap[index % 4]}"> 
       <h1>{item.name}<h1>
    </div>
))}
```

Comment: Thank you this was what I was looking for. I tried using the modulo thing but I didn't divide by 4 I was checking to see if index/1 === 1, index/2 ===2, which was a problem anytime you got past 4.